# how to disable virtual scrolling in slickgrid?

Tags: slickgrid

as title said, I want to capture all html element to generate a snapshot,but slickgrid use virtual scrolling, I got only several rows in viewport, when I scroll down, it shows blank

I need get all row dom to generate static html

Comment: virtual scrolling is a built-in feature, you can't disable it. Your question does not really follow Stack Overflow guideline, [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you for your guide, I will learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously wrote in the comment that you cannot disable virtual scrolling, however I was wrong since I forgot that you can actually disable it by using `autoHeight: true`, see [Example 11 `autoHeight`](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example11-autoheight.html)

However, there are big limitations, or at least important notes, to know about:

- using `autoHeight` means that it will create a div element **for every** single dataset row. If you have thousands of rows, this will make your DOM tree very large and can choke your browser and make is irresponsive, which is why virtual scrolling exist.
- also using this flag will move the scrolling from the grid to the browser scroll, it's not much an issue but it's noteworthy

So can you disable virtual scrolling? The answer is Yes with `autoHeight` but be aware of the consequences. If you have less than a thousand rows then that might be acceptable, however with over a thousand rows it's probably better to keep the virtual scrolling enabled.

Comment: I have already used `autoHeight`, but it generate all rows, as the question said, we capture all elements to generate a static html page that will be used by unauthorized user, so I modified nvd3.js to make it scroll behavior like virtual scrolling finally, we always want to fixed header when scrolling, and thank you for your patience!